# How access to screen in another .kv file when use splashscreen

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

**Hi everybody, I have designed a splash screen that will display the logo of the app and after 3 seconds it will be transferred to the login page. The splash and login screens are designed in two separate .kv files. The problem I have encountered is the inability to access the login screen in the `login.kv` via `main.py` I have error:

> TypeError: 'kivy.properties.StringProperty' object is not callable. How to solve the problem؟

**main.py file**

```
class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.switch_to_home,3)
    def switch_to_home(self,dt):
        self.manager.current = login.Screen.name('login')
class StartPage(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('logo.kv')
        return Builder.load_file('login.kv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    StartPage().run()
```

**logo.kv file**

```
#:include login.kv
ScreenManager:
    SplashScreen:
        name: 'Splash'
        MDLabel:
            text: "LOGO"
```

**login.kv file**

```
Screen:
    name:'login'
    MDLabel:
        text: "LOGIN"
```

Comment: In `def build(self)`  only the first line executes, so the `login.kv` is never processed. Reorder the lines and delete the first `return` and see how it works.

Comment: Please post a [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that raised the error you mentioned.

Comment: I want the logo screen to be displayed first, then login so I delete the second return and write it in the screensplash class. bu it dosn't work too.PLZ help me. How can I call the logo screen first and then(after 3sec) the login?